# why result didn't show in my swi- prolog editor?

Tags: swi-prolog

this is my editor . what is the problem?why the result didn't show (in this picture must show X=a , Y=b,c)?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5JsE.png?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure - I don't use an IDE myself, but the program works OK.  One thing to note is that you have singleton variables - does the IDE dislike that enough to stop it running ?  Try using underscores (see my image, run 3).

[image: Program in NotePad++, run in SWIPL]

Comment: i try it but the result was same,didn't show the result (my editor is not VP !!!)

Comment: I see what you're using now.  Try just using a basic text editor and swipl itself.

Comment: you clearly have SWI-Prolog installed. Go to Start / All Programs / SWI-Prolog / Prolog and do what I did above - should work fine, in which case there's something not quite right with the IDE.  To load your .pl file, use File... Consult.

Comment: Good :)  Not sure what's going on in your IDE, sometimes they're more of a hindrance than a help ;)